# Possibility to use lead and lag functions together with groupBy in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I'm interesting is there a way to use lead\lag to count something like this

First step: i have a dataframe

```
+----+-----------+------+
| id | timestamp | sess |
+----+-----------+------+
| xx | 1         | A    |
+----+-----------+------+
| yy | 2         | A    |
+----+-----------+------+
| zz | 1         | B    |
+----+-----------+------+
| yy | 3         | B    |
+----+-----------+------+
| tt | 4         | B    |
+----+-----------+------+
```

And i want to collect id's that is previous to particular id partitioning by session_id

```
+----+---------+
| id | id_list |
+----+---------+
| yy | [xx,zz] |
+----+---------+
| xx | []      |
+----+---------+
| zz | []      |
+----+---------+
| tt | [yy]    |
+----+---------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `window` over the column `sess` and `lag` the IDs as you mentioned in the question. Then you can use `groupBy` with the aggregate function `collect_list` to get the output.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val w = Window.partitionBy($"sess").orderBy($"timestamp")
val df1 = df.withColumn("lagged", lag($"id", 1).over(w))
 df1.select("id", "lagged").groupBy($"id").agg(collect_list($"lagged").as("id_list")).show

//+---+--------------------+
//| id|             id_list|
//+---+--------------------+
//| tt|                [yy]|
//| xx|                  []|
//| zz|                  []|
//| yy|            [zz, xx]|
//+---+--------------------+
```